# PowerMockito.whenNew isn't working

Tags: testing, powermockito

**Update.** Check working example in the end.

---

I've got a class:

```
package test;

public class ClassXYZ {
    private final String message;

    public ClassXYZ() {
        this.message = "";
    }

    public ClassXYZ(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassXYZ{" + message + "}";
    }
}
```

and a test:

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MockClassXYZ {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassXYZ.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(new ClassXYZ("XYZ"));

        System.out.println(new ClassXYZ());
    }
}
```

but it still creates a real class and prints:

> ClassXYZ{}

What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.** *Maven deps:*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

**Working example:**

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassXYZ.class)
public class MockClassXYZ {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ClassXYZ mockXYZ = mock(ClassXYZ.class);
        when(mockXYZ.toString()).thenReturn("XYZ");

        PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassXYZ.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockXYZ);

        ClassXYZ obj = new ClassXYZ();
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reconsider the test code that you have written. Your are printing the real object not the mocked one. 'System.out.println(new ClassXYZ());'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing a `@PrepareForTest(ClassXYZ.class)` on your test class, see the documentation [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) or [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects). From the first link:

> ## Mock construction of new objects
>
> **Quick summary**
>
> 1. Use the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation at the class-level
>      of the test case.
> 2. Use the `@PrepareForTest(ClassThatCreatesTheNewInstance.class)` annotation at
>      the class-level of the test case.
>
> [...]

---

Also note that there's no point of mocking the constructor if you ask the mocking framework to return a real instance of the mocked class.

Comment: Works like a charm. Tnx!

Comment: What about JUnit 5? What should I write instead @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)?